# How do I use the Microsoft IIS Diagnostics Toolkit to troubleshoot my problems?

Tags: php, iis, diagnostic

I have downloaded the [IIS Diagnostics Toolkit (x86)][1]

[1]: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=9bfa49bc-376b-4a54-95aa-73c9156706e7&displaylang=en and I was wondering how to use it. I'm not a system admin just a developer trying to work my way around a strange problem.

I have an iis server running php(not my choice) and every once in a while the application will not allow anyone to log in and then a little while later it just starts working again. I look in the event viewer and don't see anything and the iis logs are no help either.

I read somewhere about someone using the the toolkit to diagnose there problem. I just need a little guidance on how to use this tool. Thanks.

Comment: By the way I'm certain it is not a code problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question (using the toolkit), but have you checked the application pool recycling? You can enable the logging to see every time it recycles - you can also limit it to recycling at certain times during the day.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have upped the idle time for the application pool. I guess I'll see if that works.

Comment: That's not really what I was getting at. If you enable all the logging for the application pool, you can determine from the Event Viewer if the interruption is due to recycling. If you set it for defined times only, that can also help. If you just change the time from 29 to 33 hours (for example), you still don't know when it happens, if you don't have the logging configured properly.